# Run php in other name file

Tags: php

Example:
i have a file with name: filephp.srt

I want when run that file it will become php but the file still have that name !

Does anyone know that function can run like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a handler in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php|srt)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of a file extension is to let your computer know what type of code exists in that file. If you leave the file extention of `filephp.srt` as `.srt`, servers will not know that there is php code inside, and hence will not run it as php code, though there are probably some hacky methods of forcing a server to run a file as if it were a php file.

Comment: The *browsers* have nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Biffen oh, then if I had said "Server" instead of browser would you agree with the statement or is there something else that you thing is incorrect? I'm always open to learning

Comment: Yeah, ‘server’ would make it *closer to* correct. It's still possible to instruct the server to run any file through PHP. So this answer is still wrong, IMO.